# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type error in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to set up one of the ongoing projects on my local. After npm install when I tried to run **npm start** command I'm getting the below error on ubuntu 18.04
[image]

Here is my **babel.config.js** config file

```
 module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        modules: false,
      },
    ],
    '@babel/preset-react',
  ],
  plugins: [
    'styled-components',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
  ],
  env: {
    production: {
      only: ['app'],
      plugins: [
        'lodash',
        'transform-react-remove-prop-types',
        '@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements',
        '@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements',
      ],
    },
    test: {
      plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs',
        'dynamic-import-node',
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

Using webpack for this project, Here is the **Webpack file code**

```
/**
 * COMMON WEBPACK CONFIGURATION
 */

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = options => ({
  mode: options.mode,
  entry: options.entry,
  output: Object.assign(
    {
      // Compile into js/build.js
      path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'build'),
      publicPath: '/',
    },
    options.output,
  ), // Merge with env dependent settings
  optimization: options.optimization,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/, // Transform all .js and .jsx files required somewhere with Babel
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: options.babelQuery,
        },
      },
      {
        // Preprocess our own .css files
        // This is the place to add your own loaders (e.g. sass/less etc.)
        // for a list of loaders, see https://webpack.js.org/loaders/#styling
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        // Preprocess 3rd party .css files located in node_modules
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: 'file-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'svg-url-loader',
            options: {
              // Inline files smaller than 10 kB
              limit: 10 * 1024,
              noquotes: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              // Inline files smaller than 10 kB
              limit: 10 * 1024,
            },
          },
          // {
          //   loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
          //   options: {
          //     mozjpeg: {
          //       enabled: false,
          //       // NOTE: mozjpeg is disabled as it causes errors in some Linux environments
          //       // Try enabling it in your environment by switching the config to:
          //       // enabled: true,
          //       // progressive: true,
          //     },
          //     gifsicle: {
          //       interlaced: false,
          //     },
          //     optipng: {
          //       optimizationLevel: 7,
          //     },
          //     pngquant: {
          //       quality: '65-90',
          //       speed: 4,
          //     },
          //   },
          // },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: 'html-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: options.plugins.concat([
    // Always expose NODE_ENV to webpack, in order to use `process.env.NODE_ENV`
    // inside your code for any environment checks; Terser will automatically
    // drop any unreachable code.
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
      NODE_ENV: 'development',

      // Endpoints
      APP_DATA_CONFIG_ENDPOINT: '',
      CREATE_SESSION_ENDPOINT: '',
      CROSS_PROMOTION_ENDPOINT: '',
      AWANI_API_ENDPOINT: '',
      RANCANGAN_CONFIG_ENDPOINT: '',
      TRENDING_CONFIG_ENDPOINT: '',
      HOME_PAGE_RANCANGAN_CONFIG_ENDPOINT: '',
      RSS_CONFIG_ENDPOINT: '',
      ASTRO_AWANI_BETA_HOSTNAME: '',
      ASTRO_AWANI_HOSTNAME: '',
      SUBSCRIPTION_ENDPOINT: '',
      SFV_SEARCH_API: '',
      BREAKING_NEWS_ENDPOINT: '',
      SFV_API_ENDPOINT: '',
      ADDTHIS_SCRIPT: '',

      // Secrets
      REACT_APP_CLIENT_NAME: '',
      REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY: '',
      EMAILOCTOPUS_SECRET_KEY: '',

      // App
      SEARCH_PAGE_URL: '',

      // ULM
      ULM_CLIENT_ID: '',
      ULM_REDIRECT: '',
      ULM_ENDPOINT: '',
      ULM_MIDDLEWARE_ENDPOINT: '',

      // Variant
      VARIANT: '',
    }),
  ]),
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', 'app'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.react.js'],
    mainFields: ['browser', 'module', 'jsnext:main', 'main'],
  },
  devtool: options.devtool,
  target: 'web', // Make web variables accessible to webpack, e.g. window
  performance: options.performance || {},
});
```

Please help me to out of this problem.
Thank You

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: @Sam Added webpack file code as well, Please check

Comment: Maybe you are missing the core-js part, import "core-js/modules/es.promise";
import "core-js/modules/es.array.iterator"; see https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import/#installation